# Magento 2.4.1 layered issue with elasticsearch

Tags: layered-navigation, elasticsearch, magento2.4.1

I am having this issue. After every reindex category pages in front end keep crashing with error:

```
[2020-11-13 10:51:09] report.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [11416]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level setting."}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2_product_3_v3","node":"6dnV9snpTbWH1aYDTVwZ5Q","reason":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [11416]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level setting."}}],"caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [11416]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level setting.","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [11416]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level setting."}}},"status":400} {"report_id":"8fcb7b6507b57237d63e6fbf929b53361d99f220ca80409f966af6e9e85d12de","exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\BadRequest400Exception(code: 400): {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [11416]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level setting.\"}],\"type\":\"search_phase_execution_exception\",\"reason\":\"all shards failed\",\"phase\":\"query\",\"grouped\":true,\"failed_shards\":[{\"shard\":0,\"index\":\"magento2_product_3_v3\",\"node\":\"6dnV9snpTbWH1aYDTVwZ5Q\",\"reason\":{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [11416]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level setting.\"}}],\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [11416]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level setting.\",\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [11416]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level setting.\"}}},\"status\":400} at /public_html/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:632)"} []
```

Error is fixed when I increase in elastic node the max_result_window with this:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/_settings" -d '{ "index" : { "max_result_window" : 500000 } }' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

But when crons reindex magento it seems that elastic resets max_result_window to default 10000 and layered navigation disappears from frontend.

I use elastic 7.9 and magento 2.4.1

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies, I didn't get a notification for this. I hope this can help you or someone else.

first I added a var to the env file:

```
    'elasticsearch' => [
        'max_result_window' => 50000
    ],
```

After that created a preference:

```
<preference for="Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\Index\Builder" type="Custom\Overwrite\Model\Adapter\Index\Builder" />
```

and updated the build function adding these lines before the return>

```
    $max_result_window = $this->_deploymentConfig->get('elasticsearch/max_result_window');

        if(isset($max_result_window) && !empty($max_result_window))
        {
            $settings['max_result_window'] = $max_result_window;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you already solve this.
I just found that magento creates a new elasticsearch index each time that the reindex process is executed. That's why the max_result_window is cleared.
A workaround could be to extend the build function in Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\Index\Builder

maybe store the max_result_window in database or .env file and load it from those locations.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Could you explain more? How can I do this?